# Create Line-Chart with different X-Values

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I have a certain number of measurements. Each in the following form:

```
Table A:  
|  Time [s] | Value |
|   0.5     |   2.0 |
|  50.3     |  33.7 |
| 100.0     |  25.5 |

Table B:
|  Time [s] | Value |
|   1.3     |  12.7 |
|  27.8     |  25.0 |
|  97.5     |  20.0 |
| 100.0     |   7.1 |

Table C:
...
```

The time is always the same, from 0.0 seconds to 100.0 seconds.
The measurement-points as to be seen in the example differ.

I now want to display the different measurements in one chart. Each table has its own line-graph. The X-Axis would display the Time.

Is something like this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my problem by using a Scatter graph instead of a Line graph...

Comment: This is a very common problem. People see the icons for "Line" chart and "XY" chart, and don't realize the difference is the behavior of the X axis, not the format of the plotted data.